# Error importing a file into a file repository using R and REDCap API

Tags: r, redcap

I'm using the redcap API to try to upload a file into a file repository within a data access group:

```
library(RCurl)


#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
token <- "xyz123456"
url <- "https://redcap.myredcap/api/"
file <- '//example/my_directory/file_example.html'
formData <- list("token"=token,
                 action='import',
                 content='fileRepository',
                 folder_id=1,
                 returnFormat='json',
                 file=file
)
response <- httr::POST(url, body = formData, encode = "multipart")
result <- httr::content(response)
print(result)
```

Get this error:

```
$error
[1] "No valid file was uploaded"
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `file = file` with `file = httr::upload_file(file)` - this works for me when I directly upload files to RC (though difficult to be reproducible, I just tested it on one of my projects and it worked (though not specific to a DAG, but the only differences in the code is I dont have `folder_id = 1`):

```
formData <- list(
  "token" = token,
  action = 'import',
  content = 'fileRepository',
  folder_id = 1,
  returnFormat = 'json',
  file = httr::upload_file(file)
)
```

Comment: Thank you !  This worked.  turns out I had an existing function called upload_file, which was causing things to mess up.  Once I cleared the environment things worked just fine.  One other question - is there a parameter in the API that overwrites the existing file?  Currently, if you run this call twice, it will add the same file again and add a (1) on the end of the file name. Thanks!

Comment: The API doesn't have a parameter for overwriting a file in the File Repository. You would need to look up the document ID and delete it yourself. For future reference, I'm liking to your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77454707/redcapapi-failing-to-overwrite-file-on-file-repository-r