# redcapAPI - failing to overwrite file on file repository (R)

Tags: r, redcap

While I can get this script to work just fine (it imports a file into a file repository in a REDCap project), it fails to overwrite the existing file.

```
library(redcapAPI)

file <- 'C:/Temp/my_report.html'
rcon <- redcapConnection(token="xyz",url = 'https://redcap.project.website/api/')

importToFileRepository(
  rcon,
  file,
  folder_id = 1,
  overwrite = TRUE,
)
```

Am I missing something?  I would think `overwrite=TRUE` would overwrite the file, but it does not.

Comment: It's not reproducible. Maybe a workaround: Check if file exists, if so: delete by `file.remove(fn)`, write new file with `importToFileRepository()`, set `overwrite = FALSE`.

Comment: unfortunately, I can't get this to work.  REDCap assigns a new file ID each time I import a file, so I can't really delete it and then re-upload... I wish there was an overwrite method that would work.

Answer (score 1):

I can understand why you would want and/or expect this behavior. Unfortunately, the REDCap doesn't support an `overwrite` argument in its API method. Consequently, `importToFileRepository` doesn't support an `overwrite` argument.

It would be possible to mimic this behavior by writing a separate function that exports the contents of the File Repository folder, looks for a file of the same file name, and if one exists, captures the document ID to delete after importing the new file.

I'm pseudocoding this, so please don't expect it to work out of the box, but something like

```
importWithOverwrite <- function(rcon, file, folder_id, overwrite = FALSE, ...){
  if (overwrite){
    FileRepo <- exportFileRepositoryListing(rcon,
                                            folder_id = folder_id)
    current_doc_id <- FileRepo$doc_id[FileReport$name == basename(file)]
  }

  is_success <- importToFileRepository(rcon,
                                       file = file, 
                                       folder_id = folder_id, 
                                       ...)

  # Only delete the existing file if the import is successful first
  if (is_success && ovewrite){
    deleteFromFileRepository(rcon, 
                             doc_id = current_doc_id)
  }
}

file <- 'C:/Temp/my_report.html'
rcon <- redcapConnection(token="xyz",url = 'https://redcap.project.website/api/')

importWithOverwrite(rcon, 
                    file = file, 
                    folder_id = 1, 
                    overwrite = TRUE)
```

If you have a GitHub account, you can submit an issue at https://github.com/vubiostat/redcapAPI/issues. These kinds of needs are pretty warmly received among their group.